# I'm getting data from select through POST and it's not working properly with conditional statements even after using isset?

Tags: php, html

I am fetching data from HTML written in my page and below this, I have my PHP code connected to an `Oracle` database on the same page. I am unable to check and compare the value rightly.

It's giving always false, I don't know why. I am able to resolve this using my `chooseQuery` variable as `truthy/false` but I want to know the reason of not working this condition. I think it may be only my server/machine related problem but I want to know the other reason if exists.

**HTML Code:**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <label for="chooseQuery">Choose Query :</label>
  <select name="chooseQuery" id="chooseQuery">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose one of the following to get data</option>
    <option value="Direct Approval Mod ID wise">Direct Approval Mod ID wise</option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
  <label for="start_date">Start Date :</label>
  <input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1 week')); ?>">
  <label for="end_date">End Date :</label>
  <input type="date" id="end_date" name="end_date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

**PHP Code :**

```
    if($con = $config->connectDB('imblrtR')){
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $chooseQuery = isset($_REQUEST['chooseQuery']) ? $_REQUEST['chooseQuery'] : '';
      $start_date = isset($_REQUEST['start_date']) ? $_REQUEST['start_date'] : '';
      $end_date = isset($_REQUEST['end_date']) ? $_REQUEST['end_date'] : '';
      echo "\n".$chooseQuery;
      if($chooseQuery!=0 && $chooseQuery!='' && $chooseQuery!='0')
      {
        echo "ok";
        //getData($chooseQuery,$start_date,$end_date);
      }
      else{
        echo "Choose Right Option";
      }
      oci_close($con);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "not connected\n\n";
  }
```

This is always printing `Choose Right Option` even after showing `$chooseQuery` value as `Direct Approval Mod ID wise`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$chooseQuery!=0` condition was not being met because when comparing a string with integer, PHP tries to convert that string to an integer. if it can't, then that string is evaluated as 0. so your condition `$chooseQuery!=0` basically became `0!=0` which failed everytime.

Change your conditional statement to below.

```
if(!empty($chooseQuery))
  {
    echo "ok";
    //getData($chooseQuery,$start_date,$end_date);
  }
  else{
    echo "Choose Right Option";
  }**strong text**
```

Comment: I can use this but I want to know the reason that why my conditional statement is not working?

Comment: your this condition `$chooseQuery != 0` was not being met. This evaluates to true because it is converted to  an integer when compared with an integer. If PHP can't properly convert the string then it is evaluated as 0.

Comment: Can you please tell me that if I compare not-null string with an integer, then will it also convert it into a number?

Comment: yes. so if the string that you are comparing is numeric, then it will be converted into a number, it not 0 will be assumed.

Comment: What if the string is not numeric, then will it be converted into any integer like as length of the string? I think this is done in `C`.

Comment: if the string is numeric, then it is converted to a number, for example, if `$a = "123";` then $a will be converted to number 123 on integer comparision. If however the string is NOT numeric, then they are evaluated as 0. So comaprisions like `"assd" ==0` will result to true and  `"assd" !=0` will result to false.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
if($chooseQuery!=0 && $chooseQuery!='' && $chooseQuery!='0')
```

to

```
if(!empty($chooseQuery))
```

It should work if you are getting any value in $chooseQuery variable!